# Page Title not showing up in the breadcrumb - SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, publishing-site, master-page, branding

I am trying to include current page title after site name on a sharepoint 2010 publishing site. 
The master page that I have created contains the necessary control to render the page title as attached in the screenshot below :- 
MasterPage Entries
[image]

However when the page is loaded in the browser , the page title does not show on the right to the site name. I checked with firebug and saw that the title value did not load inside the h2 tags as it normally does. Kindly refer to the screenshot below for the same.
[image]
Page Load in Browser

Can somebody help me over here to exactly if there is something I am missing ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server" />` is the actual value that should get you the page Title.

If you want to use this in Publishing sites you would need to adapt as here http://blog.sharepointrx.com/2010/01/10/fixing-sharepoint-breadcrumbs-to-remove-the-pages-node-and-display-the-page-title-instead-of-the-aspx-page-name/

Comment: I tried your solution but didnt work at the first instance. I realized that show pages option was unchecked in the current navigation settings. After I enabled that, it worked like a charm.

Thanks Marius for a speedy solution.

Comment: Happy could help,
C:\Marius